# How do I install an older version of Nuget package and its dependencies and save them to packages.config

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am trying to install a version of a package that is not the latest on the public Nuget repository. (because each version requires blessings from the corporate technology controls department) With the Package Manager UI in Visual Studio 2012, I did not find an option to install an older version. With the commandline tool, I don't see an option to save the package version and its dependency versions into packages.config (which the UI does automatically). The package has 50 dependencies and sub-dependencies. Is there a way to achieve both older version and save to packages.config?

Comment: Did you try the Package Manager Console window inside Visual Studio? You can specify an exact version using the `Install-Package` command with the `-version` parameter.

Comment: Yes, but it didn't save the resolved package dependencies infomation into packages.config. It doesn't work for me unless you can provide documentation on how to generate packages.config.

Comment: Install-Package will add the dependencies into the packages.config file. If you install jQuery.Validation it will add jQuery.Validation and jQuery into the packages.config file. You should not need to do anything else but without looking at what your NuGet package's .nuspec looks like it is difficult to know what is happening.

Comment: You are right. I have been misinformed. I had a different problem to begin with. But looks like this question is a duplicate.